# Is it true that $L_\alpha \prec L_\beta$ implies that $V_\alpha\prec V_\beta$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Given two ordinals $\alpha<\beta$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta$, is it necessarily true that also $V_\alpha\prec V_\beta$? is the converse of this implication true?
I'm working on a set theory homework and, if this is true, I got it. However, I don't know if this is actually true. I wouldn't know at first how to prove it or how to find any counter example, so any hint would be welcomed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true - in fact, it's outright disprovable. For example, we have the following:

1. $V_\alpha\not\preccurlyeq V_{\omega_1}$ for any countable ordinal $\alpha$.
2. There **is** a countable $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\preccurlyeq L_{\omega_1}$.

Both of the facts above require proof, but they're good exercises; I've put spoilered hints below.

Hint for 1:

> If $\alpha<\omega_1$ then (either $\alpha$ is finite and things are boring or) $V_\alpha$ contains a well-ordering of $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$ which implies $V_\alpha\models$ "There is a countable well-ordering not isomorphic to any ordinal."

Hint for 2:

> This is actually a consequence of a much more general result: working in an at-most-countable language, if $\mathfrak{A}$ is any structure and $(\mathfrak{A}_\beta)_{\beta<\omega_1}$ is a sequence of *countable* structures such that $$\mathfrak{A}=\bigcup_{\beta<\omega_1}\mathfrak{A}_\beta,$$ $$\beta<\gamma\implies\mathfrak{A}_\beta\subseteq\mathfrak{A}_\gamma,$$ and $$\lambda\mbox{ limit}\implies \mathfrak{A}_\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}\mathfrak{A}_\beta,$$ then there is some $\eta<\omega_1$ such that $\mathfrak{A}_\eta\preccurlyeq \mathfrak{A}$. To apply this result here, note that - **unlike for the $V$-hierarchy** - we have $\vert L_\alpha\vert=\aleph_0$ for each countably infinite $\alpha$. *(This hint can be pushed beyond countable "pieces;" the key new notion is **cofinality**.)*

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! ALso, i don't know if this changes anything, but would it matter if $\alpha$ was a regular cardinal? is there any way to have stronger hypothesis such that this works?

Comment: Don't we also need to assume that the language is also countable for that theorem to hold?

Comment: @Math_Images_Only Quite right, fixed! Good catch.

Comment: @SusanaSantoyo Nope - even if $\alpha$ is a regular cardinal this can break down. You need strong assumptions on both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, as well as on the whole set-theoretic universe in general (namely [$\mathsf{V=L}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) seems pretty key), to get this to hold. In general, the $L$-hierarchy and $V$-hierarchy behave *very* differently.